# Static resources unavailable when the community website is disabled

Tags: visualforce, community, static-resources

We have a public static resource `Portal_bundle` that contains the JS & CSS that is used on the community website

The same static resource is used in a custom maintenance page that is displayed when the community is disabled

The problem is when we disable the community :

- The custom maintenance page is displayed (OK)
- The static resource become unavailable (503) the JS & CSS doesn't get loaded (NOK)

[image: error]

Any suggestion ?

Answer (score 1):

We ran into the same issue and this seems to be a bug. We had to load an image in a visualforce image and since the static resource did not load the workaround we used was to use the base64 content of the image directly in the image tag like below

```
<img width="16" height="16" alt="star" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhEAAQAMQAAORHHOVSKudfOulrSOp3WOyDZu6QdvCchPGolfO0o/XBs/fNwfjZ0frl3/zy7////wAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACH5BAkAABAALAAAAAAQABAAAAVVICSOZGlCQAosJ6mu7fiyZeKqNKToQGDsM8hBADgUXoGAiqhSvp5QAnQKGIgUhwFUYLCVDFCrKUE1lBavAViFIDlTImbKC5Gm2hB0SlBCBMQiB0UjIQA7" />
```

Another important point is even if the community is de-activated it will show a blank page if you directly access pages of community. Its a salesforce bug

check it out [here](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000000EAUtQAO) in salesforce issues. this issue is applicable for Napili community template not sure of the other ones though.